# A key on my keyboard isn't working that well

Tags: keyboard

I have a (mechanical) razer blackwidow ultimate, probably 2013, doesn't say on the box really. I have had it for around a year, and my S key has sstopped working that well. Sometimess it put 2 SSs, sometimes it doesnst put any Ss at all. I have tried to fix thiss typing but forget it, it would take too long. I have ussesd a air can duster thing to clean it, doesnt work. I can take off the key-cap thing, the thing you press down on that looks cool, and it still doesnt work that well. Can someone please help me with my problem?? the second half of thisss seemed to work well because i backspaced multiple time. and S key very hard pressed down to put it on screen, sometime still doenst even work. PLEASE HELP ME.

ok test (S-space-s-space):    ss     s  s s                                 s.
you cant see it, but it took me 30 times for the last one to work. /-/ LOL

Comment: Time for a new keyboard or live with ss s ss ss s

Comment: yep, time for a new keyboard

Comment: rule of thumb? Old/original model is blue, second gen onwards is green. That said, I think my BW's hitting 4 years + and still going strong.

Answer (score 1):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luHI4UjkyCY) describes how to disassemble and replace key switches on the Razor BlackWidow. Soldering is required. Cherry key switches can be [bought at Digi-key](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?s=10322&FV=fff40011%2Cfff80061%2C2dc0933%2C2dc0936) (the BlackWidow appears to use the [MX1A-E1NN](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MX1A-E1NN/CH196-ND/40084)). (There are other sources, this is the one I know about.)

Comment: Newer ones *might* use razer's custom switches - which arn't quite cherry blues. I'd be tempted to suggest harvesting/reusing a macro key switch as a replacement if it isn't a cherry blue

Comment: or you could swap out a key you never use? I swapped out the - on keypad to repair mine.